# Need to do Update Query using Inner Join

Tags: sql

How do we write the Update query for the below Select Query:

```
SELECT spo
FROM t2 
INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.aa= t1.aa and t2.bb= t1.bb and t2.cc= t1.cc
WHERE t1.isk = <User Input>
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: which column you want to update can you give more info

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL You can use something like:

```
UPDATE t2 
INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.aa= t1.aa and t2.bb= t1.bb and t2.cc= t1.cc
SET spo = <What You want here>
WHERE t1.isk = <User Input>;
```